# Rails asset pipeline compiled js error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, production

When I'm in development mode, everything works and I have the following .js import order:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ujs/src/rails.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/1modernizr.custom.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/2rainyday.0.1.2.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/3xrain_init_youtube.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/3xxbootstrap.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/4classie.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/5modalEffects.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/6jquery.placeholder.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/7jquery.custom.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/8script.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#countdown").countdown({
                    date: "3 march 2014 12:00:00",
                    format: "on"
                },

                function() {
                    // callback function
                });
    });

</script>
```

And in production, it's like the following:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/assets/application-afbc85ff07d9057a50dee5713b8bccdf.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#countdown").countdown({
                    date: "3 march 2014 12:00:00",
                    format: "on"
                },

                function() {
                    // callback function
                });
    });

</script>
```

The problem is I'm getting some erros in production mode that I can't understand. The First error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'countdown'
```

The call to countdown is after the import of the application.js, so why is it happening? Is it possible that the inline script is being executed before application.js? If so, why that does not happen in development with separated files??

The second error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null
```

**Update:**

If I put a setInterval I solve the first error, like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(1000, function(){
              $("#countdown").countdown({
                  date: "3 march 2014 12:00:00",
                  format: "on"
                  },

                  function() {
                            // callback function
                  }
              );

        });
   });

</script>
```

So I think the inline script is being executed first. That's very weird.

Comment: Yes I did, it's the last one, 8script.js.

Comment: Try putting the setInterval inside the document.ready rather than outside it

Comment: Try to precompile the assets with rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production  before you deploy the app

Comment: @Baloo, you're right but that is just a test that is indicating the inline script is being executed before all the application.js file, but that is a wrong behavior I think.

Comment: @deep, I just did it, but there is no error in the precompilation process.

Comment: Can we get a look at your application.js?  I honestly can't see anything wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: Sure, I just added the git url sou you can check everything if you want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any reason why the js isn't just in app/assets

Comment: The third party scripts are in vendor. You have to bower install to make it work(it adds new files to vendor/components).

Comment: @Jirico  I had the same problem, solved it by precompiling the assets locally and then pushing the compiled assets to production.

Comment: @deep but I'm getting the same error in my local machine in production mode. The only think I can think(a hack) is to copy the files to public folder and serve they separately. But I really would like to know the reason of these problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing that error because of the one before it: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null`

This happens in production because all the JS is in one file and if there's an error then the rest of it isn't executed. It works in development because `5modalEffects.js` is a separate file so the error in that file doesn't affect any others.

I managed to fix the modal error by adding the `.md-close` class to the close modal button inside `div#modal-1` and this solved the other issue :)

Comment: Nice! You were right. The first error does appear in development mode and it was causing the countdown error. Thanks and sorry for take your time :)